# text cannot be placed above image

Tags: positioning

I would like to place a text above an image, but latex do what it will.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{ngerman}{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{document}
...Anzahl die Lags, die über Confidence interval sind, gering sind, werden solche Störungen auch als wertvolle Informationen anerkannt.
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{D:/MA/Bilder/window256lag15time2401}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{Abbildung}
\centering
 \caption{ \textit{ Die Fensterlänge ist 128 .Die Bilder von links; wenn drei, fünf, sieben Autokorrelation-Koeffizient über Confidence interval linie ist.} }
\end{figure} 
Sollte die Anzahl die oben stehende confidence Interval Lags hoch sind, wird die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die wervolle Informationen extrahiert wurde, höher.   

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{D:/MA/Bilder/5acf-11-13}
\renewcommand*{\figurename}{Abbildung}
\centering
 \caption{ \textit{ Von Links, wenn die Anzahl die Lags, die über das confidence interval sind, 11, 13 und 15 sind.} }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But see no text between these two images. What I see is like this:

[image]

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It looks like you want to place the text directly above the floating figures. Well, the figure will float away, but not the text. Is the text directly connected to the figure, it should be placed inside the caption. Or drop the floating by omitting the figure environment and replacing `\caption{` with `\captionof{figure}{...`, provided, you use `\captionof`

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Did you try the solutions @ChristianHupfer suggested?

Comment: @Kaja: I should clearify, that I meant the `caption` package and the `\captionof` command in my last comment.

Comment: I thought the purpose of \caption was to use the figure counter, not to restrict putting text into a figure environment.  At the you should be able to include a \parbox{\textwidth}{}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The purpose of `\caption` is not just to provide automatic counting of figures and table but even more important providing some description what is shown in the figure(s) or table(s).

Comment: It is one thing to provide a service, and another to preclude competition.

Comment: Off-Topic: You are typesetting german text. Maybe you want to join [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/), the german version of TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: Let the figures float

Floating environments are in general better than stationary ones, because it helps LaTeX in deciding where to place the pagebreaks. If you enforce "stationary floats" you will most likely get the contents of your page spread out (unless you use e.g. `\raggedbottom`)

```
documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont=it}
\begin{document}
\ldots Anzahl die Lags, die über Confidence interval sind, gering sind, werden solche Störungen auch als wertvolle Informationen anerkannt.
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{D:/MA/Bilder/window256lag15time2401}
  \caption{Die Fensterlänge ist 128 .Die Bilder von links; wenn drei, fünf, sieben Autokorrelation-Koeffizient über Confidence interval linie ist.}
\end{figure} 
Sollte die Anzahl die oben stehende confidence Interval Lags hoch sind, wird die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die wervolle Informationen extrahiert wurde, höher.   

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.2]{D:/MA/Bilder/5acf-11-13}
  \caption{Von Links, wenn die Anzahl die Lags, die über das confidence interval sind, 11, 13 und 15 sind.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## Method 2: Force the figures to stay

Just replace all `figure` environments by `center` (you can now omit `\centering` inside). Because the `caption` package is already loaded to adjust the caption font, we can use

```
\captionof{<float type>}{<text>}
```

where `<float type>` is in this case `figure`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont=it}
\begin{document}
\ldots Anzahl die Lags, die über Confidence interval sind, gering sind, werden solche Störungen auch als wertvolle Informationen anerkannt.
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=.4]{D:/MA/Bilder/window256lag15time2401}
  \captionof{figure}{Die Fensterlänge ist 128 .Die Bilder von links; wenn drei, fünf, sieben Autokorrelation-Koeffizient über Confidence interval linie ist.}
\end{center} 
Sollte die Anzahl die oben stehende confidence Interval Lags hoch sind, wird die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass die wervolle Informationen extrahiert wurde, höher.   

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=.2]{D:/MA/Bilder/5acf-11-13}
  \captionof{figure}{Von Links, wenn die Anzahl die Lags, die über das confidence interval sind, 11, 13 und 15 sind.}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image]